# How to get processes to which debugger was attached to during last debugging session

Tags: c#, vsx, envdte, vs-extensibility, vspackage

I'm trying to write Visual Studio package which allows attach to processes chosen in previous debugging session. Basically, I know how to attach to processes:

```
var dte = GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;
if (dte != null)
{
    IList<Process2> processes =
        dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses.Cast<Process2>()
            .Where(process => process.Name.IndexOf("process.exe", StringComparison.Ordinal) != -1)
            .ToList();
    foreach (var p in processes)
    {
        p.Attach();
    }
}
```

The question is, how to get processes which I have been attached to last time? Is there any information stored about this? If not, how to write logic which helps me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IVsDebuggerEvents` (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.dll) provides notification when the debugger changes mode while `IDebugEventCallback2` (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop.dll) is used by the debug engine to send debug events. Usage of these interfaces will allow to gather required information.

**UPDATE:**
Detailed example of how to do it is shown on my github repository where I've written [Visual Studio extension](https://github.com/JaroslawWaliszko/Resurrect) which allows to attach debugger to previously debugged processes.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any such information.
A different approach which might work is to add a WCF service to each
process. This service will enable you both to launch a debugger , 
and also to check if a debugger was launched already.

```
 public class DebugService : IDebugService
    {
        public void LaunchDebugger()
        {
            //TODO - write some code indicating that this 
            //process was bebugged. e.g. - mark a flag in DB or file
            Debugger.Launch();
        }

        public bool WasDebuggedLastTime()
        {
            //TODO - write code to check if this process was debugged
        }

    }
```

Comment: It's not an option for me.